# Xamarin.Forms - can run on iPhone simulator, but not on actual connected iPhone device

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, mobile-application

Windows Machine:

```
Windows 10 (OX Build 18363.1440)
VS 2019 16.9.4
Xamarin 16.9.000.273
Xamarin.iOS & Xamarin.Mac SDK  14.14.2.5
```

Mac Machine:

```
Big Sur 11.3.1
VS 8.9.8 (build 7)
XCode 12.5
Xamarin iOS 14.14.2.5
```

I have been working my way through any and all info I can find online, to jump through all the necessary hoops to get VS on my windows dev machine to compile and run the iOS project in my Xamarin.Forms solution.  I have automatic provisioning selected, have my apple account connected, have the device registered at developer.apple.com.

I've gotten to the point where I can run it on a simulator (on the mac ... won't run the simulator on the windows machine), but I can't get it to deploy on the actual iPhone device I have attached to the mac machine.  The list of errors and warnings I get is below.  I don't know how to start working past these or fix them.

ERRORS:

Failed to codesign 'bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone8.1-13.1.3/FirstApplicationPackt.iOS.app': Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "Apple Development: [user]" /Users/abe/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/FirstApplicationPackt.iOS/[guid]/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone8.1-13.1.3/FirstApplicationPackt.iOS.app:errSecInternalComponent

/usr/bin/codesign exited with code 1

WARNINGS:

[xma]: An error occured when trying to start the forwarded port from '51549' to '53643'

An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
at ...
... at Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.MessagingService.d_80.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\230\s\src\Xamnarin.Messaging.Ssh\MessagingService.cs:line 309

[xma]: An error occured while trying to connect.  Details: No details provided

An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
at ...
... at Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.PortForwarder.StartForwardedPort(Int32 boundPort, Int32 port, ForwardedPortType type) in C:\A\1\230\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh\PortForwarder.cs:line 109

Grateful for any help.

Comment: Please do not post errors as images.  The first thing I would do to help you is google the specific error message, but that's difficult to do with an image.

Comment: Jason - I have edited the question to remove the image and replace it with text versions of the errors and warnings.  Hope that helps.

Comment: have you searched on "unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer" - there are a LOT of hits

Comment: Jason - yes, I have, and discovered as you did that all kinds of things come up.  I posted the issue here hoping that someone who is experienced working with this kind of set up would recognize the problem and could point me in the right direction.  As I'm sure you are well aware, error messages don't always do a good job describing the actual problem.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/665139

Comment: Haved you tried using VS Mac to build and run on actual device? I mean, without involving pc at all. I recommend making sure it works there first.

Comment: For the wanring "unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer", did you try to reset the certificates. Here is a similar issue [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/86161).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your helpful suggestions.  I did try building it directly on the mac, and discovered that did not work either, so realized there was a bigger problem.  Following Kyle's suggestion I found that my developer certificate was not being trusted.  I tried several "fixes" that were posted various places online but to no avail.  I ended up recreating the certificate and it was then trusted.

App still would not deploy on the connected device however.   But I tried creating a new project in Visual Studio on the mac and it did deploy as expected.  I then tried creating a new project on the Windows machine, and it, also, deployed to the connected device as expected.  Apparently the existing apps were connected to the certificate that was not trusted.